# Determining word boundaries in LuaTeX node list

Tags: luatex

What should be considered best practice regarding determination of word boundaries in LuaTeX node lists?

I see that some packages use something like this:

```
while ((MOVE.id == node.id("glyph")) or (MOVE.id == node.id("kern")) or (MOVE.id == node.id("disc")) or (MOVE.id == node.id("hlist"))) do
    MOVE = MOVE.next
end
```

But I wonder if there can't be problems there, e.g. with packages inserting other nodes.

Currently I use:

```
if MOVE.id == node.id ( "glue" ) or ( MOVE.id == node.id ( "kern" ) and MOVE.subtype == 1 ) then break end
```

On p. 72 of the luatex manual, tables are shown that display word boundary rules for hyphenation:

[image]

So should I include boundary nodes?

Why should a penalty or kern node necessarily indicate the end of the word??

What does "otherwise: yes" mean?

Comment: I have long grappled with the LuaTeX documentation and have come to the conclusion that it's garbage. In most places it incomplete and/or very superficial. Unfortunately, the only way to find out what the code is doing right now is reading the source: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/tree/trunk/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir

Comment: More specifically, what you are looking for is probably here: https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/a7578ef54e1528f398f50aa910816332460866c5/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lang/texlang.c#L817-L929

Comment: @HenriMenke I certainly agree that the LuaTeX reference manual is far from ideal (to say the least). However, here I'm not really concerned with what the LuaTeX code does, but what is generally the best way to determine the beginning and end of a word in a LuaTeX node list. (I am working on a package where, for it to work properly, it needs to be decided if the next glyph is still part of the word or not.)